# using wget to get selected subdirectories

Tags: wget

I want to set up a cron job to download data from a server (http). Each directory is date/time-stamped in the format `YYYYMMDDHH`, where there are 2 versions daily, so HH is either 00 or 12. I only want a few of the subdirectories in each of those. eg the directory structure is `website/2013121800/subdir/moresubdirs/file`.
I tried using `wget -A "*/subdir/*"` but it started getting everything else. Is there a way to use wget to get only the desired subdirectories without explicitly setting the date/time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -X '/*/subdir'
```

should do the trick for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Directory-Based Limits](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits) instead of [Types of Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html#Types-of-Files) contraints.

Use:

```
wget -X '/*/subdir'
```